# CPT issue: Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback

Tags: custom-post-types, warnings

I'm getting an error on the admin screen for the custom post type. I've searched lots of other answers but see nothing in my code that could be causing it. Here's my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// Register the post types and taxonomys
add_action('init', 'register_post_types');
function register_post_types(){ 
// Property Post Type
$labels = array(
    'name'               => __('Properties'),
    'singular_name'      => __('Property'),
    'add_new'            => __('Add New'),
    'add_new_item'       => __('Add New Property'),
    'edit_item'          => __('Edit Property'),
    'new_item'           => __('New Property'),
    'view_item'          => __('View Property'),
    'search_items'       => __('Search Properties'),
    'not_found'          => __('Nothing found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon'  => '',
);

$args = array(
    'labels'               => $labels,
    'public'               => true,
    'publicly_queryable'   => true,
    'show_ui'              => true,
    'register_meta_box_cb' => 'custom_meta_boxes',
    'query_var'            => true,
    'menu_icon'            => null,
    'rewrite'              => true,
    'capability_type'      => 'post',
    'hierarchical'         => false,
    'menu_position'        => 5,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'genesis-seo', 'thumbnail','genesis-cpt-archives-settings' ),
    'has_archive' => true,
); 

register_post_type('property' , $args);

// Property Taxonomy
$taxononmy_args = array(
    'hierarchical'   => true, 
    'label'          => "Categories", 
    'singular_label' => "Category", 
    'rewrite'        => true,
    'show_admin_column' => TRUE
);

register_taxonomy("property_categories", array("property"), $taxononmy_args);
}
```

Comment: Does the error give you a line number? If so, what line is it?

Comment: those are very generic names for your cpt and functions, also can you indent your function appropriatley? It's difficult to read

Comment: _I'm getting an error on the admin screen for the custom post type_ Is that the only screen you're seeing the error? If the error was part of registering post type (which is hooked to `init`), I'd expect that error anywhere.

Comment: Imho is this the reason for the error: *function 'custom_meta_boxes' not found or invalid function name*. ?!

Comment: Doesn't look like there's something wrong with your CPT declaration. Have you tried removing it? Does it make the error disappear?

Comment: The full error is here - sorry, I meant to include it.

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'custom_meta_boxes' not found or invalid function name in /nas/content/live/waldendev/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 298

My indents are there when I look at it Tom - sorry if they aren't coming through.

Comment: The error is ONLY showing on the admin screen for the properties, nowhere else. Charles I see that, but all of that is core WordPress, isn't it?

Comment: Note: I don't think I was getting the error until I ran the WP 4.8 update. Rolling back to see if that makes a difference...

Answer (score 1):

I've removed the custom_meta_boxes. I don't have to have them and it solves the problem. I still don't understand why they were a problem, but if I can do without them I will.

I appreciate everyone's efforts.

Note: rolling back to 4.7 made no difference.

Comment: If there is no function by the name `custom_meta_boxes` then it'll fail when it tries to call `custom_meta_boxes()`, that's where the warning comes from

Answer (score 0):

where is your `custom_meta_boxes` function where you are adding your meta boxes?

Please see this [URL](https://wptheming.com/2010/08/custom-metabox-for-post-type/) for creating a custom meta box for the custom post type.
After adding this function your code will work fine.